# Using the same SELECT SQL query in multiple unions

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We have some expensive query in Snowflake that we want to use in multiple union statements:

```
select 
    g.a as a,
    c.trial as trial,
    a1.x as value,
    g.valuename as valuename,
from 
    (select  
         date, x, 
         dense_rank() over (order by "date") as trial
     from 
         condition_table 
     order by 
         trial desc) c
join 
    acc table_1 on a1.id = c.aid
join 
    gspecs g on g.z = c."z"
             and g.valuename = 'xyz'

union

select 
    g.a as a,
    c.trial as trial,
    a1.x as value,
    g.valuename as valuename,
from 
    (select  
         date, x, 
         dense_rank() over (order by "date") as trial
     from 
         condition_table 
     order by 
         trial desc) c
join 
    table_2 a1 on a1.id = c.aid
join 
    gspecs g on g.z = c."z"
             and g.valuename = 'wsx'
```

Notice that

```
from 
    (select  date, x, 
 dense_rank() over (order by "date") as trial
 from condition_table order by trial desc)
```

Is used multiple times, which is not ideal. One solution is to put it into a temporary table but it does not work for us as we want a single self-contained query that can be used in a view for example. Any way to reuse the same query in several union statements without duplicating it ?

Comment: your assumption, "that it is not ideal" should be tested. nbk's use CTE is the correct "reuse" solution, but on some forms of data access, doing the work twice is faster than doing it once, and the synchronization cost between them consumer pipelines. To see if this is the case, run it both ways.. use the faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

snowflake supports Common Table Expression (CTE) which you can use, to produce a temporary table

```
With CTE as (
select  date, x, 
    dense_rank() over (order by "date") as trial
 from condition_table order by trial desc)
select 
    g.a as a,
    c.trial as trial,
    a1.x as value,
    g.valuename as valuename
from 
    CTE c
join acc table_1 on a1.id = c.aid
join gspecs g on g.z = c."z"
and g.valuename = 'xyz'
union
select 
    g.a as a,
    c.trial as trial,
    a1.x as value,
    g.valuename as valuename

from 
   CTE c
join table_2 a1 on a1.id = c.aid
join gspecs g on g.z = c."z"
and g.valuename = 'wsx'
```